# does mobile safari not support the feDisplacementMap svg-filter?

Tags: css, svg, mobile-safari, svg-filters

I tested some feDisplacementMap svg-filters.
they are well displayed on Safari on macbook.
but mobile-safari of my iphone doesn't display them.

it is one of example.

```
<svg id="svgeffects">
  <defs>
    <filter class="safari_only" id="liquify">
        <feTurbulence baseFrequency="0.015" numOctaves="3" result="warp" type="fractalNoise"></feTurbulence>
        <feDisplacementMap id="liquid" in="SourceGraphic" in2="warp" scale="35" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="B"></feDisplacementMap>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

https://codepen.io/MikeMcChillin/pen/QOJNVE

Is it unusable filter for mobile-safari?
or Do I need other work?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the SVG filter itself, it's the fact that you're referencing it via a CSS filter. A number of SVG filter primitives don't work when called from a CSS filter in Mac/iOS Safari. If you apply this filter directly to an SVG shape it works fine. For example:

```
<svg id="svgeffects">
  <defs>
    <filter class="safari_only" id="liquify">
        <feTurbulence baseFrequency="0.015" numOctaves="3" result="warp" type="fractalNoise"></feTurbulence>
        <feDisplacementMap id="liquid" in="SourceGraphic" in2="warp" scale="35" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="B"></feDisplacementMap>
    </filter>
  </defs>
<rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50" filter="url(#liquify)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot of sense. Deleted my (incorrect) answer.